# Dragging one of multiple circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am playing around with a great tutorial from here http://ssun.azurewebsites.net/creating-a-draggable-object-in-d3/. I am having a problem understanding what is passed through functions such as call. For example, how can I choose one of two circles. The modified code is below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Load D3 from site -->
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- End CSS (Styling) -->
    </head>
      <body>

    <h3></h3>

  <!-- Begin D3 Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var boxWidth = 600;  
    var boxHeight = 400;

    var box = d3.select('body')  
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'box')
            .attr('width', boxWidth)
            .attr('height', boxHeight);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
             .on('dragstart', function() { circle.style('fill', 'red'); })
             .on('drag', function() { circle.attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                                            .attr('cy', d3.event.y); })
             .on('dragend', function() { circle.style('fill', 'black'); });


     var circle = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle')  
                .data([{ x: (boxWidth / 3), y: (boxHeight / 3), r: 25 },{ x: (boxWidth / 2), y: (boxHeight / 2), r: 25 }])
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                .call(drag)
                .style('fill', 'black');

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, only one is selected and the other disappears. How do I reference a specific circle? When writing anonymous functions for call, how do I discover what arguments they pass?

Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You handler should access the target node using

```
d3.select(this)
```

instead of `circle.`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <!-- Load D3 from site -->
        <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

    <!-- End CSS (Styling) -->
    </head>
      <body>

    <h3></h3>

  <!-- Begin D3 Javascript -->
  <script type="text/javascript">

    var boxWidth = 600;  
    var boxHeight = 400;

    var box = d3.select('body')  
            .append('svg')
            .attr('class', 'box')
            .attr('width', boxWidth)
            .attr('height', boxHeight);

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
             .on('dragstart', function(c) { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red'); })
             .on('drag', function(c) { d3.select(this).attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                                            .attr('cy', d3.event.y); })
             .on('dragend', function(c) { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black'); });


     var circle = box.selectAll('.draggableCircle')  
                .data([{ x: (boxWidth / 3), y: (boxHeight / 3), r: 25 },{ x: (boxWidth / 2), y: (boxHeight / 2), r: 25 }])
                .enter()
                .append('circle')
                .attr('class', 'draggableCircle')
                .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x; })
                .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y; })
                .attr('r', function(d) { return d.r; })
                .call(drag)
                .style('fill', 'black');

  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, that is plain and simple, very elegant! Would this also enable me to somehow track the index of that object? I would like to update the data in real time, not just the position on screen.

Comment: Yes, you can access the data and the index, they are passed to the event handler: `.on('dragstart', function(d, i) { console.log('the data', d, 'the index', i)})`

Comment: Thank you! You've been an immense help!

Comment: I would bother you for just one tiny help, since you've been so kind. Changing the global dataset variable from within the callback fails - is this the asynchronicity?

    var drag = d3.behavior.drag()  
             .on('dragstart', function() { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'red'); })
             .on('drag', function(d,i) { d3.select(this).attr('cx', d3.event.x)
                                            .attr('cy', d3.event.y); dataset[i] = d; console.log(dataset);})
             .on('dragend', function() { d3.select(this).style('fill', 'black'); });

The console log works.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Perhaps it's best you asked a separate question